# Too many abstract functions - OOP Best practices

Tags: oop, abstract-class

How many abstract function declaration of an Abstract class is too many?

For example, for a membership based payment system :

Multiple payment modes are supported :

- Credit Card
- Token (a Credit Card payment but using a token)
- Redirect (i.e Paypal)
- Manual (admin charging manually the user)

I have an abstract class PaymentMode and different modes above extend to this class.

Each mode has its own unique logic of the methods below and i have to declare abstract methods in PaymentMode class for these

```
// each mode has own way of validating the customer data
validate();

// own logic of cleaning customer data (e.g removing/adding/updating)
preparePaymentData();

// returns a string for saving in database, subclass must implement so developers plan to extend the PaymentMode abstract will be forced to return the correct value
getModeOfPayment();

// each mode has its own logic when determining payment gateways to attempt
getGatewaysToAttempt();

// before sending the payment to gateway, each mode has its own logic when adding specific data
addCustomDataSpecificForGateway();

// check if transaction has failed, different payment modes has different logic of determining a failed transaction
isTransactionFailed()
```

There 6 unique logic for each mode, I've managed to commonized the common codes already and put it inside the PaymentMode class.

This number may grow as we implement new features that is unique to each mode.

In my mind, im concerned that if any future developer extends my PaymentMode class, he has to implement all the abstract function declarations.

So does a large number of abstract function declarations an indication of a **BAD DESIGN**? How much is too many?

If its a bad design then, can you recommend any techniques or Design Patterns that will solve this issue

Thanks

Comment: If your abstract class really has no implemented functionality, and you do not expect that it will, then you could consider just using an _interface_ instead.  An interface would be a very appropriate thing to use if you want to describe _behavior_ of payments without specifying exactly _what_ that behavior is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for your suggestion, but my abstract class has functionalities in it since these different payment modes share some common functionality

Comment: I don't see anything evil about having a handful of abstract methods.  You could also consider using both an interface and an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without specifics, but:

Obviously there is no hard limit on abstract methods (methods in interfaces or abstract classes), although less is always clearer and easier to understand.

What *is* indicating a suboptimal design however is that you need to modify your abstraction of a payment method with each new payment method. That to me indicates a failing abstraction. OOP is not just about pulling common code out, avoiding duplication, it is about abstractions also.

What I would look into is to somehow **transfer the control** (the *real* control) to the payment method. Trust the payment method, delegate the task of making the payment to it.

What I mean by that is, you *retain* control somewhere, where you ask the payment method to do specific parts of its job (with the parts being different for different concrete methods). Steps like `validate()`, `prepare...()`. And also, you expect it to give you the "gateway", so now code outside the payment method (even if it's the superclass) must know what that is, or how to handle it.

Instead of doing all that, try to come up with a design, that transfers full control over to the payment method, so it can do it's job without outside code assuming any particular set of steps.

For example:

```java
public interface PaymentMethod {
    Receipt payFor(Bill bill);
}
```

The `PaymentMethod` here is responsible for doing everything itself. Redirecting the user, saving the receipt in the database, whatever is needed. Once you feel comfortable with this "main" abstraction (it covers all use-cases), you can work to create smaller abstractions that cover details like saving to database, if it is the same for all methods.

In relation to that: don't use abstract parent classes as a way to share code between classes, that is not exactly what inheritance is for. Create proper abstractions for the different "pieces of code", and let them be used by "bigger" abstractions (i.e. composition).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such number of abstract functions declarations that is BAD although the huge number could mean the design has flaws. Just pay attention to Single responsibility principle.

You have already defined that you have 4 modes - so i think you should do 4 interfaces for each mode in your case. After doing this you can see what is the common for all 4 of them and extract the base interface. You may consider to extract 6 unique logics for all of them also as interfaces...